# Getting a blank csv file out of php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have read alot of questions about this, and I have tried all of the code in those questions, and I have came up with this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="teste.csv";');

$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach ($StockReady as $line) {
    fputcsv($f, $line, '||');
}
fclose ($f);
```

My file outputs some js that I have in the header:

[image]

My array `$StockReady` is like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111|1|1861||
    [1] => arm_2|1|998745||
    [2] => 111|2|-94||
    [3] => arm_2|2|4899.04113588||
    [4] => arm_teste|2|140.958||
    [5] => 111|3|2||
    [6] => arm_2|3|-77||
    [7] => arm_teste|3|5021||
    [8] => 111|4|-28||
    [9] => arm_2|4|15||

......
```

Like I said: I have tried all the code that I found searching this topic and my file keeps outputing that js. Anyone has an idea of what could be? Thanks

Comment: Where is the JS that's being outputted coming from?

Comment: all of this is in my controller the JS to. Ive took the JS out, and it puts others echo's that i have in the controll into the file. Only have model and controller cuz this is going to be a SFTP controller.

Comment: Anything echoed out will appear in the output.

Comment: Why doenst it contain the rest of the echos? why only the js? is there anything i can do to chose what goes into the file?

Comment: wrong syntax here - header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="teste.csv";'); Try - header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=teste.csv');

Comment: So i deleted everything besides the function to get items and the foreach, now the file comes completely blank. Ive tried to change the header too. in  ````fputcsv($f, $line, '||');```` my $f outputs  ````resource id ='6' type='stream' ````

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your array should be returned as csv divided by '|'. As it is already in the right format why not try good old "echo" and "implode"?

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=teste.csv');

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $StockReady);
```